# Execute code within window.load if content takes longer than 7s to load

Tags: javascript, jquery

As it says in the title I've got a window.load line:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
   //Some Code
});
```

So once everything is loaded I execute `//Some Code`, however I want to make it so if content is not loaded, lets say within 7 seconds (maybe large image file, or missing file occurs etc..) than execute `//Some Code` even if content is not fully loaded.
How can I achieve this task?

Comment: Missing file can be detected with `img.onerror = function() { ... }` btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this :

```
function someCode() {
    if (someCode.done) return;
    someCode.done = true;
    clearTimeout(t);
    // Some Code
}
var t = setTimeout(someCode, 7000);
$(window).load(someCode);
```

Comment: so I assume instead of dosomething, I need to put same code that I have inside my window.load, correct? Is there any way that would not require duplicated code?

Comment: @IlyaKnaup I'm not totally sure I get what you mean. Is the code now what you want ?

Comment: @IlyaKnaup No, you should place your code *inside* the `someCode` function. This way there is not code-duplication. The remainder of the code could stay as destroy wrote it.

Comment: @dystroy sorry for confusion, basically if I take code from you'r answer and instead of //Some Code I place code that was in original window.load, will it work so when window loads run that code, if window takes more than 7s to load run that code anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Since deferred objects can only be resolved once, that can be used as a solution:

```
var runCodeDeferred = $.Deferred(function(deferred){
    $(window).load(deferred.resolve);
    setTimeout(deferred.resolve,7000)
});

runCodeDeferred.done(function(){
    //Some Code
});
```

The same can be done with the `$.Callbacks` object:

```
var callbacks = $.Callbacks("once");
$(window).load(callbacks.fire);
setTimeout(callbacks.fire,7000);
callbacks.add(function(){
    //Some Code
});
```

But it's no different than doing:

```
var timer;
function someCode() {
    //Some Code
}
$(window).on("load.someCode",function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    someCode();
});
setTimeout(function(){
    $(window).off("load.someCode");
    someCode();
},7000);
```

Comment: They all do the trick right? Which one would you consider to be more elegant solution? I'm thinking callbacks?

Comment: Well, using deferred or callbacks looks cleaner in my opinion, but has more overhead than using the 3rd option or destroy's method. The thinking behind the three ways i did it was keeping the load logic outside of the `//Some Code` area just to keep things simple.